# Performance SATA 1.5Gb/s controller and SATA 3Gb/s harddisk

Tags: hard-drive, performance, sata

Afaik it's no problem to use a SATA 1.5Gb/s controller with a SATA 3Gb/s harddisk (spindle, non-SSD) due to SATA backwards compatibility (ignoring Force150/OPT1 issues for now).

To my understanding the interface speed will be throttled to 1.5 Gbps in this case, but what I don't understand and want to know is: does this throttling affect the read/write performance of the harddisk?

Say, I have a SATA 3Gb/s harddisk which has a sustained data rate of about 65 MB/s.

This 65 MB/s is far away from the maximum transfer rate of even a SATA 1.5Gb/s (150 MB/s) controller.

Would using a SATA 3Gb/s controller yield a (significantly) better read/write performance with the given harddisk than a SATA 1.5Gb/s controller? And if so, why?

Comment: The read/write is limited by the hardware itself. SATA is just the data bus. If a HDD can only write 65 MB/s then thats the data cap of the bus itself.  increasing the size of the bus won't change that fact.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It likely would (by about 8% or so) for one simple reason -- SATA 3Gb/s controllers typically support [NCQ](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Native_Command_Queuing) and SATA 1.5Gb/s controllers typically don't.

Comment: Keeping in mind that the Hard drive itself also has to support NCQ.

Comment: Almost all hard drives that support 3Gb/s SATA also support NCQ.

Comment: True. I misread the original question. oops.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz: ah, now that makes sense, thank you. Is this **by about 8%** some standard rule of thumb, or from your personal experience?